# Is it possible to create a VPN connection shortcut on home screen?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, home-screen-shortcuts

I want to be able to connect to my VPN connection whenever I am connected to wifi, is it possible to add a shortcut on the home screen where the widget including wireless, Bluetooth, GPS, sync and brightness options is?

Comment: Did you try the answer? Were you successful using it?

Comment: @Sid: Not yet, I'd rather do it directly using the phone capabilities without installing those apps. I might try them soon!